# Can KerasClassifier wtih TF model works with sklearn.cross_val_score when setting n_job=-1 and TF runs on a single GPU?

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, keras, cross-validation

I have this sample code and it can only runs with `n_jobs=1`.

Tensorflow backend is running on a GPU.

When I run with `n_jobs=-1` on method `cross_val_score`, the program jams/stops working or give any output, after output 4 lines `Epoch 1/100` (as I have a 4 core CPU I assume it will use all 4 cores to do CV and each trys to start a tf session on GPU)

```
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout

def build_classifier():
    classifier = Sequential()
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 11))
    classifier.add(Dropout(0.3))
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
    # classifier.add(Dropout(0.3))
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))
    classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    return classifier
classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn = build_classifier, batch_size = 100, epochs = 100, verbose=0)
accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator = classifier, X = X_train, y = y_train, cv = 10, n_jobs = 1)
```

I have also tried to limit the TF GPU usage in this way but n_job=-1 still won't work.

```
np.random.seed(123)
tf.set_random_seed(123)
config = tf.ConfigProto(inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.1 # in my case this setting will use around 1G memory on GPU
set_session(tf.Session(config=config))
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue, I use the below lines of code

## Configure GPU to use all the memory

```
config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 1.0
set_session(tf.Session(config=config))

def build_classifier():
    classifier = Sequential()
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 11))
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))
    classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    return classifier
classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn = build_classifier, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100)
accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator = classifier, X = X_train, y = y_train, cv = 10)
mean = accuracies.mean()
variance = accuracies.std()
```

then I removed the **n_jobs = -1** then I tried to run it again and check the GPU utilization using GPU-Z below is a photo from the run.

Maybe your question is you don't feel the performance enhancement using GPU. To answer this question I run the same code with CPU and GPU.

GPU at least in my average experiment 3:1 CPU. I believe it should take less than the time but this is the max performance achieved.[image: GPU Run experiment]

You can also found some good discussions [Run Keras with GPU](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmachinelearning/comments/6bjd3m/does_keras_use_gpu_processing_power/)